# Como exibir um layout no HomeScreen Widget para cada dia da semana?

Tags: java, android, datetime, google-calendar, widget

Gostaria de mostrar determinado layout no HomeScreen Widget, para cada dia da semana.

Tenho os 5 dias, e ao identificá-los, o dispositivo deve atualizar o layout do widget.

Como poderia faze-lo?

Answer (score 2):

Você precia usar a classe [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) para marcar uma notificação onde todo dia em um horario X você seja notificado pelo Sistema em seu [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), este recebera a notificação atraves do metodo [onReceive()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29) e ai você executa o que você desejar, como por exemplo alterar o layout do widget.

[Aqui](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) temos o material em inglês da propria google, estando ele dentro da propria documentação do android exemplificando isso.

---